# Pandas nested for loop insert multiple data on different data frames created

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops, data-science

I am new to data science and I am currently practicing to improve my skills. I used a data set from kaggle and planned how to present the data and came across a problem.

What I was trying to achieve is to insert data to different data frames using a for loop. I have seen an example of this and used the dictionary to save data frames but the data on the data frame is overwritten.

I have a list of data frames:

```
continents_list = [african_countries, asian_countries, european_countries, north_american_countries,
          south_american_countries, oceanian_countries]
```

This is an example of my data frame from one of the continents:

```
    Continent   Country Name   Country Code    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014
7    Oceania      Australia         AUS        11.4    11.4    11.7    12.2    13.1
63   Oceania         Fiji           FJI        20.1    20.1    20.2    19.6    18.6
149  Oceania     New Zealand        NZL        17.0    17.2    17.7    15.8    14.6
157  Oceania   Papua New Guinea     PNG         5.4     5.3     5.4     5.5     5.4
174  Oceania   Solomon Islands      SLB         9.1     8.9     9.3     9.4     9.5
```

I first selected the whole row for the country which has the highest rate on a year:

```
def select_highest_rate(continent, year):
    highest_rate_idx = continent[year].idxmax()
    return continent.loc[highest_rate_idx]
```

then created a for loop which creates different data frames for each separate years which must contain all the continent and its corresponding country and rate on that year:

```
def show_highest_countries(continents_list):
    df_highest_countries = {}
    years_list = ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014']
    for continent in continents_list:
        for year in years_list:
            highest_country = select_highest_rate(continent, year)
            highest_countries = highest_country[['Continent','Country Name',year]]
            df_highest_countries[year] = pd.DataFrame(highest_countries)
    return df_highest_countries
```

[here is what it returns: different data frames but only for the last continent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk820.png)

*Question: How do I save all the data(continents) on the same data frame? Is it not possible with dictionaries?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are overwriting the *year* index with each loop and hence only the last continent dataframe with years 2010-2014 remains:

```
df_highest_countries[year] = pd.DataFrame(highest_countries)
```

You could add *continent* for a more unique dictionary key then concatenate to one final dataframe:

```
df_highest_countries[continent+str(year)] = pd.DataFrame(highest_countries)

finaldf = pd.concat(df_highest_countries, join='outer').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Alternatively, consider avoiding the nested `for` loops by concatenating all together at the beginning, then `melt` the data for `groupby` aggregation. Then, keep only those country records with such max values for each year and continent. You can pivot with `pivot_table` back to year columns if needed.

```
df = pd.concat(continents_list)

# MELT FOR YEAR VALUES IN COLUMN
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Continent', 'Country Name', 'Country Code'], var_name='Year')

# AGGREGATE HIGHEST VALUE AND MERGE BACK TO ORIGINAL SET
df = df.groupby(['Continent', 'Year'])['value'].max().reset_index().\
        merge(df, on=['Continent', 'Year', 'value'])

# PIVOT BACK TO YEAR COLUMNS
pvt = df.pivot_table(index=['Continent', 'Country Name', 'Country Code'],
                     columns='Year', values='value').reset_index()
```

Comment: I am very grateful for answering my problem. I have never encountered `melt` and `pivot_table`. Upon reading the documentation, I am amazed of how it works. It's a good to know. Thank you very much for sharing this information! At first I also thought of how to not have a nested for loop but with what I currently know, it was really hard for me to think on how to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help on an interesting question. Indeed, these pandas methods tend to deviate from the general python with `for`, `if`, `while` etc. methods.